# How to get findstr to only print out text after the found string?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file that finds "@todo:" in my .hcpp and .h files, that looks like this:

```
@echo off

findstr /n /i /c:"@todo:" *.cpp
findstr /n /i /c:"@todo:" *.h
```

When I run it it produces output like this:

```
console.cpp:23: char message[2048]; //@todo: make this better
```

But I want it to only print out the `@todo: make this better` part, and not the text to the left of it. How can I achieve this in a batch file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findstr` does *always* return the whole line, so you need another method to split the line. Substring substitution with [set](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) is a good candidate here:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in (type *.cpp *.h ^|find /i "@todo:") do (
  set "line=%%a"
  echo/!line:*@todo=@todo!"
)
```